# Database Is not loading

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a strange question in Microsoft SQL Server v6.5 (it's better to say, it is strange for me).

When I create a new database it goes to loading and nothing happen for that.

I await for that, 24 hours but nothing happened and its still loading.

For example I will create `DBTest1`.

After creating it will show me `DBTest1(Loading)`, and nothing happens...

Meanwhile I have to say, I have to install it in my VM. I try it in different VM and also different computer. but still nothing....

If anyone got same problem, please help me.

I searched a lot in internet, but its almost nothing.

Comment: Seriously - SQL Server **v6.5** ?!?!? This is not just ooooooold - this is **ancient**! Time to upgrade !!

Comment: Some information about it over here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/oCNIpLAFeXY/D48FOkQTBuoJ

Comment: I'm not sure, but as far as I remember it is possible to attach 6.5 database to the instance of SQL Server 2000 (or restore its backup). Have you tried it? At least this version should be more manageable. Here is a link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966518.aspx